# Configure Google Apps Script callback for Slack slash command

Tags: google-apps-script, slack-api

TL;DR - **I would like to setup a Slack slash command that works on Google Apps Script.** How do you recommend I do so?

*Context:*

I currently use [google.com/script](https://www.google.com/script/start/) with Sheets to trigger a webhook call to Slack when someone fills out a Google Form. [Here it is for reference](https://github.com/mbbroberg/google-app-scripts/tree/master/slack-push). My question is an additional feature I'd like to add that won't overlap with this code.

I want to listen in Google Apps for a Slack slash command, so I've been looking through tons of examples of callbacks. I don't understand the dance necessary to get this going. Here are the variables:

- I've setup the Slack slash command, which asks for a URL and method type (POST or GET), then gives me a `token` for verification of the outgoing payload.
- I've setup OAuth 2.0 client IDs on Google APIs, which provides a `client ID` and `secret token`.
- The Google Apps tutorial [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2) offers `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback`, but if I'm reading it correctly in [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) it would require user authorization

I've reviewed other questions that mention callback ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054530/google-app-script-callback-confusion) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118634/google-app-script-callback-from-mail-body)) but haven't found anything relevant.

Guidance toward the next steps of just being able to configure a callback URL and understand how it will authentication and ultimately consume the API call from Slack in Google would be awesome.

Comment: If it's not too much too ask, you maybe want to accept my answer ? Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are on the right track, i'm fiddling around with this since couple of weeks so maybe this helps:

**Google App Script**

1. Publish > Deploy as Web App > Version: New / Execute the App as : Me / Who has access: Anyone Even Anonymous
2. You'll get a url for that web app something like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/xxx-ver-long-number-xxx/exec`
3. Copy that

**Slack Integrations**

4. Create new Slash Command
5. Method POST / URL: Paste `The url from your web app`
6. Copy the Secure Token, you need it in the Google App Script
7. Set all the other settings as you like.
8. Don't forget to save

**Back to Google App Script**

8. Copy paste this basic stuff

   ```
    function doPost(request) {

    //// SET SECURITY TOKEN (FROM SLACK COMMAND)
     var your_token = "YOUR_SLASH_COMMAND_TOKEN"; 
     var output;

    //// GET PARAMETES FROM SLACK POST REQUEST
     var params = request.parameters;

    //// ... and store them into variables
     var cmd_token = params.token; // or params.token[0] idk

    //// CHECK RECEIVED TOKEN AGAINST YOUR SAVED TOKEN
     if (your_token == cmd_token) {
        output = {"text":"SUCCESS"};
     } else {
        output = {"text":"INVALID TOKEN"};
     }

    //// SEND RESPONSE BACK TO SLACK
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(output)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
    }
   ```
9. Save script and again publish the script as web app (you have to do this everytime you change something, always choose "new" as version

**Additional Info**

This is the stuff you get from every slash command. In the example above I only use `token` ...

```
token=gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
command=/weather
text=94070
response_url=https://hooks.slack.com/commands/1234/5678
```

Works perfect for me, hope it helps :) Good luck !

Comment: With your codes, I get always error message: 401_client_error for a POST call from slack command, may that require auth2.0 ? any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Albert There is a big chance something has changed by Google since last year, I ll try to reproduce with a new example and get back to you !

Comment: Many thanks in advance. Another doPost()/slackCommand project case I can find online is this one http://googleappscripting.com/doget-dopost-tutorial-examples/ , which doesn't work neither. FYI, not like failure from command to GAS web app, a simple call to API like http://loripsum.net/api/plaintext does work good, so yes, looks problem is on Google side.

Comment: @Albert I tested the workflow again with a fresh Slack Command + a fresh GAS project. I could replicate the `401_client_error` you were seeing. The way one publishes the script ( Publish as Web App ) is crucial here and Google did change something in fact. The new way worked for me: Publish > Deploy as web app > Project Version : New > Execute the app as : Me > Who has access : Anyone, even Anonymous. (The Who has Access part changed) Now I don't get the `401_client_error` anymore. Hope this helps. I updated my answer above.

Comment: Thank you Pascal, it works now. I'm reading another excellent detailed post by @Tanaike on Github https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script#AccesstokenforaccessingtoWebApps , he point out this topic in his case4, according to him, your previous sharing setting requires a sharing of script file now, I did but still failed, maybe should we add at least Drive scope even I cannot see any Drive access in your code? another issue is how to grant access in browser for POST request. I need to write some scope involved script to see how this work. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out another great Article ! Much appreciated ;)